# Sometimes parse object with byte array column is saved but the byte array isn't saved properly

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using this code:

```
ParseObject newPObject = new ParseObject("animals");

newPObject.put("name", "dog");

newPObject.put("sound", soundAsByteArray);

try {

    newPObject.save();


} catch (ParseException e) {


}
```

98% of the time everything saved great and I can get the file perfectly in the parse data browser, but 2% of the times I get this error:

```
<Error><Code> AccessDenied</Code> <Message>Access Denied</Message> <RequestId>****</RequestId> <HostId></HostId> </Error>
```

There isn't any exception when saving the object and the object itself appear in the data browser.

Answer (score 0):

So after not getting any help from the parse team I decided to take matters into own hands, this is what I did:

1. Added to the object a number column that is called byteArrayLength
2. Defined in the cloud code a before save function with this code:

   ```
   var animal = request.object;

   var bytesArrayLength = animal.get("byteArrayLength");
   var sound = animal.get("sound");

   Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
       url: sound.url(),
       success: function(fileResponse) {

         if (bytesArrayLength == fileResponse.buffer.length) {

           // Checked out - Continue with save

           response.success(); // Continue to the after save

         }
         else {

           // Something bad happened and we need to save the animal again

           response.error("Bytes length is not equals to the real length, need to re-upload sound");

         }

       },
       error: function(error) {
           response.error(error);
       }
   });
   ```
3. In the client code I catch the exception and retry the upload

Works like a charm.